# Bash script: Asking for sudo password only once

Tags: bash, sudo

I'm working on a backup bash script, which does a bunch of long `rsync` jobs. Some take up to 3 or 4 hours each.

After these big transfers, I wish to flush the disk cache after syncing the files before running some checksums on the target disk to make sure everything is on the target disk was backed up OK. I've got this line below that supposedly does this, requiring `sudo`:

`sudo sh -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'`

In order to complete the entire bash script uninterrupted, I'm asking for the user password at the start for `sudo`, but I notice `sudo` understandably keeps the password session for something like 15 minutes only. After several hours the script stops waiting for the user to enter the `sudo` password again.

What would be the best way to run this script to keep `sudo` permissions for when they're needed, but without requesting a password each time so the script runs uninterrupted for several hours, retaining the ability for the disk cache flush command?

```
#!/bin/bash

# backup all drives using rsync and also verify the integrity of the backup

    # BACKUP

    # first, drop the disks internal volatile caches to start with clean file system state (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30970/)
    printf "\nNeed sudo priviliges in order to flush disk caches in this script.\n"
    # invoke sudo to ask for permission needed to clear the disk cache in next command
    sudo printf "\nClearing disk cache... " 
        sudo sh -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
    printf "DONE.\n\n\n"

    # now run the backup lines
        # First disk
        printf "rsync 'First' disk...\n"
        # need to put [] around $ to escape it for folders like $RECYCLE.BIN (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305010)
        rsync -vah --progress --stats --exclude={"Adobe","[$]RECYCLE.BIN","System Volume Information","pagefile.sys","temp"} /media/n/First/ ./First/
        printf "\n\n"

        # Scratch disk
        printf "rsync 'Scratch' disk...\n"
        rsync -vah --progress --stats --exclude={"[$]RECYCLE.BIN","System Volume Information","pagefile.sys","temp"} /media/n/Scratch/ ./Scratch/
        printf "\n\n"


        # ...



    # CHECKSUM
    # re-read/compare

    # drop the disks internal volatile caches
    printf "Now testing backup checksums for integrity.\n\n"
    # rsync --itemize-changes, legend here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493525)

        # First disk
        printf "Clearing disk cache... "
            sudo sh -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
        printf "DONE.\n"
        printf "Checking 'First' disk backup...\n"
        # need to put [] around $ to escape it for folders like $RECYCLE.BIN (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305010)
        rsync -vah --progress --checksum --itemize-changes --stats --exclude={"Adobe","[$]RECYCLE.BIN","System Volume Information","pagefile.sys","temp"} /media/n/First/ ./First/
        printf "\n\n"


# ...



print "Finished.\n\n"

# revoke sudo
sudo -k
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your script with sudo.

```
sudo yourscript.sh
```

You will be asked only once, and the script will run with root privileges.

Comment: How to avoid running `rsync` as root?

Comment: You can use `sudo -u username` to run commands under a specific user.

Comment: `$USER` will still be defined inside the script (run with `sudo`), so you can use `sudo -u $USER` in @GeraldSchneider 's comment.  Furthermore, you can make a new script containing `sudo yourscript.sh` so you don't have to remember to use `sudo`.  That's especially useful in cases where the script doesn't need sudo permission until later.

Comment: some commands do not exist when run with sudo eg. `sudo -u $USER composer`

Comment: @brad set the necessary PATH variable for root or use absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

use (as root) visudo (or edit /etc/sudoers directly) and add:

```
# below "root ALL=..."
jonny      ALL=NOPASSWD: your_script
```

Note: the script  must be in one of the "secure_path" in /etc/sudoers

Comment: To avoid some programs to run as root: start them with "sudo -u xxx my_program"